# How do I get all sub-nodes of an XML document?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML document that models this hierarchy of tasks:

```
1     Customer
1.1   Product A
1.1.1 Task Alpha
1.1.2 Task Beta
1.2   Product B
1.2.1 Task Alpha
1.2.2 Task Gamma
2     Customer
2.1   Product W
2.1.1 Task Delta
```

Unknown number of Customers, Products, and Tasks per product.  There can also be an unknown number of subtasks, so we could see this:

```
19.16.8.17.1 Subtask Something
```

The XML looks like this:

```
<ROWSET>
    <ROW>
        <PROJECT_CODE>Don't Care</PROJECT_CODE>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <PROJECT_CODE>WBS</PROJECT_CODE>
        <TASK_DETAIL>
            <TASKS>
                <TASK>
                    <TASK_CODE>1</TASK_CODE>
                    <TASK_DESCRIPTION>Customer 1</TASK_DESCRIPTION>
                    <TASKS>
                        <TASK>
                            <TASK_CODE>1.1</TASK_CODE>
                            <TASK_DESCRIPTION>Product A</TASK_DESCRIPTION>
                            <TASKS>
                                <TASK_CODE>1.1.1</TASK_CODE>
                                <TASK_DESCRIPTION>Task Alpha</TASK_DESCRIPTION>
                                <TASKS />
                                <TASK_CODE>1.1.2</TASK_CODE>
                                <TASK_DESCRIPTION>Task Beta</TASK_DESCRIPTION>
                                <TASKS />
                            </TASKS>
                        </TASK>
                        <TASK>
                            <TASK_CODE>1.2</TASK_CODE>
                            <TASK_DESCRIPTION>Product B</TASK_DESCRIPTION>
                            <TASKS>
                                <TASK_CODE>1.2.1</TASK_CODE>
                                <TASK_DESCRIPTION>Task Alpha</TASK_DESCRIPTION>
                                <TASKS />
                                <TASK_CODE>1.2.2</TASK_CODE>
                                <TASK_DESCRIPTION>Task Gamma</TASK_DESCRIPTION>
                                <TASKS />
                            </TASKS>
                        </TASK>
                    </TASKS>
                </TASK>
                <TASK>
                    <TASK_CODE>2</TASK_CODE>
                    <TASK_DESCRIPTION>Customer 2</TASK_DESCRIPTION>
                    <TASKS>
                        <TASK>
                            <TASK_CODE>2.1</TASK_CODE>
                            <TASK_DESCRIPTION>Product W</TASK_DESCRIPTION>
                            <TASKS>
                                <TASK_CODE>2.1.1</TASK_CODE>
                                <TASK_DESCRIPTION>Task Delta</TASK_DESCRIPTION>
                                <TASKS />
                            </TASKS>
                        </TASK>
                    </TASKS>
                </TASK>
            </TASKS>
        </TASK_DETAIL>
    </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

My first attempt at an XSLT is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="ROW">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="PROJECT_CODE[.='WBS']"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="PROJECT_CODE">
    <h1><xsl:value-of select="."/></h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Task Code</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="./../TASK_DETAIL/TASKS/TASK">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="TASK_CODE"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="TASK_DESCRIPTION"/></td>
        </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="./TASKS/TASK">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="TASK_CODE"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="TASK_DESCRIPTION"/></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

As you can see, I'm taking a very naive approach to parsing this thing.  I would like to list all the tasks & subtasks of my particular WBS, no matter how many levels deep it goes.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like musikk beat me to an explanation, but here's a demo xslt that does what I understand you want. In general, avoid xsl:for-each for most of the things you think you should use for-each for (i.e. for which you would use for-each in other languages). Instead, use apply-templates or call-templates as musikk says. Read up on modes (mode="foo") too if you have to process the same content several times (e.g. to generate a table of contents and then the body and then an index).

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="ROW[./PROJECT_CODE='WBS']">
    <h1><xsl:value-of select="PROJECT_CODE"/></h1>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Task Code</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="TASK">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="TASK_CODE"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="TASK_DESCRIPTION"/></td>
    </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces:

```
    <html>
   <body>
      <h1>WBS</h1>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <th>Task Code</th>
            <th>Description</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Customer 1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>1.1</td>
            <td>Product A</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>1.2</td>
            <td>Product B</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Customer 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2.1</td>
            <td>Product W</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you check your formatting for me?  it's not coming through.

Comment: Sorry about that, it's fixed now.

Comment: This is giving me what I want, except it's matching even the Project Codes that don't match 'WBS', so I'm getting way too much stuff.  It also doesn't generate any of the `<th>` or `<h1>` elements, so I think that whole second template isn't matching.

Comment: changing to this: `match="ROWSET[./ROW/PROJECT_CODE='WBS']">` made the `<th>` elements show up, but the `<xsl:value-of select="PROJECT_CODE"/>` still isn't working.

Comment: I started from scratch with what you gave me, and I got it to do what I want when I changed to this: `<xsl:template match="ROW[./PROJECT_CODE=WBS']//TASK">` in the third template.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry I missed your replies. I guess I don't have this site configured to notify me about replies to things I've posted. I'm glad you got things working though.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of nesting `xsl:for-each` directly just declare a few templates with `xsl:template` and call them (recursively) via

1. `xsl:call-template` if there is a specific named template you want or
2. `xsl:apply-templates` if a template should be used based on an XPath expression (which in your case might be as simple as "task"

For basic usage `xsl:apply-templates` should be enough but sometimes you want to match a specific rule.

I would do it like this (note this is quite rough... I think you can figure out the details with a little help from e.g. [w3schools](http://w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_w3celementref.asp)):

1. one template for `tasks` and one for `task`
2. the template for `tasks` walks over the `task` nodes and calls the `task` template for each `task` node
3. the `task` template itself calls the `tasks` template again if there is a `tasks` node

Comment: Thanks for the broad overview.  I started at W3 schools, but wasn't able to piece things together from them.